# Объяснить лексические ошибки и записать правильный вариант

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он завсегда вежлив - он всегда вежлив.
Иметь роль - играть роль.
Гостиница для командировочных - ?
Играть значение - иметь значение.
Так ведёт себя только невежда - он ведёт себя как невежда.

Comment: @кристи, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

1. Завсегда (просторечие) обычно относят к действиям, ожиданию каких-то действий, готовности их совершать (он завсегда с тобой выпьет), т.е. в речи связывают с глаголом - здесь не тот случай.
2. "Иметь роль" (быть занятым в роли) можно актёру в спектакле, но это выражение не применяется в переносном смысле (играть роль = "иметь значение", "влиять на что-л.").
3. Формально правильно "командированный". Командировочный - неформальное наименование, вполне уместное в ряде ситуаций (она познакомилась с командировочным), но не в документах, где указано назначение гостиницы.
4. См. (2) "играть значение" - результат ошибочного переноса глагола из выражения "играть роль".
5. Возможно, здесь проявилось недопонимание различия слов "невежда" (несведущий человек) и "невежа" (грубиян, человек, всегда ведущий себя невежливо). Первое выражение выглядит логичным только со словом "невежа", второе - с обоими словами (ведёт себя как невежда = судя по его действиям, не знает элементарных вещей).

Comment: Александр, вы считаете, что в предложении Так ведёт себя только невежда -  слово "невежда" - неправильно?  Т.е. неуч себя так вести не может?

Comment: Выражение возможное, но в нём странное обобщение: будто существует представление о том, как ведут себя невежды (я бы не смог дать их общему поведению определение - оно даже не всегда проявляется). Во второй фразе речь идёт о конкретном случае, и можно понять, почему так выразились.

Answer (score 1):

Он завсегда вежлив - он всегда вежлив. - завсегда - просторе., малограмотное.
Иметь роль - играть роль. -- На сцене роль актёр играет. В пьесе есть (имеется) роль для пожилого актёра. Актёр: У меня есть заветная роль, которую я мечтаю сыграть.
Гостиница для командировочных - для командированных. Командированный - человек на задании.   Командировочные - то, что связано с заданием: документы, деньги, билеты...
Играть значение - иметь значение. -- Значение может быть или не быть. Оно не актёр, потому и не играет. Играют роль, т.е. представляют собой кого-то или нечто другое. 
Для меня деньги не имеют значения, имеет значение их количество.
Так ведёт себя только невежда - он ведёт себя как невежда. -- Если о неприемлемом поведении, то *невежа, от* не вежливый. -- Если об отсутствии знания, то *невежда, от* не ведать. Оба предлож. верны.

Answer (score 0):

Гостиница для командировок.

> Командиро́вочные мн. разг. Денежные средства, предназначенные на расходы по командировке
> Так ведёт себя только невежда-он ведёт себя как невежда -  можно сказать и так, и так. Оба варианта корректны.